# Perché 'di per sè' si scrive con 'è', mentre 'in sé' con 'é'? Qual è la differenza fra 'sè' e 'sé'?

Tags: orthography, accents

Perché 'di per sè' si scrive con 'è', mentre 'in sé' con 'é'? Qual è la differenze fra 'sè' e 'sé'? Thank you.

Comment: Per piacere, Kyriakos, sta attento agli apostrofi, specialmente in questo sito: “qual è”, non *“qual'è”.

Comment: Dove hai visto *“di per sè”?

Comment: secondo me *"di per sè" è semplicemente un errore.

Comment: @mau Devo ammettere che anche a me capita di scriverlo sè, semplicemente perché la "é" richiede di tener premuto lo Shift e a volte me ne dimentico se digito velocemente o, per sbaglio, lo rilascio prima di aver premuto il tasto con la "è".

Comment: @Baku, e se usassi di più la penna?

Comment: io uso la tastiera logica US-International, per me è ed é pari sono (ë è più complicata perché ci vuole lo shift)

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Il problema è che difficilmente un compilatore riesce a scannerizzare e effettuare l'analisi grammaticale del testo di un programma scritto a mano. Senza contare che sarei molto più lento, senza aiuti dell'editor, niente autocompletamenti etc. Parecchio scomodo insomma.

Answer (score 9):

Actually it is "[di per sé](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/se/)", always with "é". I don't think "sè" is an Italian word, it's probably a mistake for "sé".

Answer (score 9):

I have never heard about such a rule. The pronoun *sé* wants the acute accent, because the vowel is closed.

Of course, one can find *sè* in old books, because the distinction between acute and grave accent on *e* became widely used only during the second half of the twentieth century. There is no acute accent in the 1830 edition of a [famous novel](http://books.google.it/books?id=7UkTAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=promessi%20sposi&hl=it&sa=X&ei=En4CU_OqDYLhywPK_oCwAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=promessi%20sposi&f=false)

[image: Page 9]

[image: Page 10]

One can clearly see *nè anche* and *da se*.

The orthographic norm has since changed; now the distinction between grave and acute accent is “mandatory”. But *sé* shouldn't be pronounced with an open *e* and so it wants the acute accent.

Answer (score 3):

Nel primo caso l'accento è semplicemente sbagliato, infatti non troverai in alcun dizionario della lingua italiana la parola "sè".

Trattandosi in entrambi i casi della stessa parola intesa nella stessa accezione, ovvero nella funzione di pronome riflessivo, vanno scritti entrambi con accento acuto (é) (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/se/), salvo in casi in cui l'uso dell'accento per distinguere il "sé" pronome dal "se" congiunzione sia completamente superfluo perchè impossibile confonderli (come ad esempio qui: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/accentazione-pronome-stesso)

In conclusione, la differenza tra "sè" e "sé" è che la prima non esiste.